# Order By using parameter varchar(100)

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, parameter-passing

Can I do `"ORDER BY"` by passing parameter if there's more than 1 column in parameter?
For example, the `parameter` is '`number asc,name`' , how i can use the passed parameter to `order by`?

Comment: Try dynamic sql. Or break down the sort params into multiple params and then use case statements in ORDER BY. See https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/dynamic-sorting/

Comment: how this parameters stored in the table? in the same way?

Comment: @DK Ok sir , i will try the suggestion thanks a lot

Comment: I already try read the explanation and try to using dynamic sql but i think its seems little bit confusing @DK

Comment: whats confusing? post some code if you need further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE..WHEN..` here

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM @table
ORDER BY (CASE @SortItem WHEN 'number asc' THEN number END) asc,
         (CASE @SortItem WHEN 'name desc' THEN name END) desc
```

Comment: So we need to write all possibility case that will be happened? @AbdulRasheed

Comment: for dynamic sorting , YES. Otherwise you can try dynamic sql, but its not a good practice.

Comment: Dynamic sql is little bit hard to understand, I try it and fail @AbdulRasheed